# Interpolation Search Program?

Tags: c, search, interpolation

When I enter a value up to about 200000, there is no problem with it. But if I search a bigger value program just does nothing. Just passes one row down and wait. What is the problem with this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int isearch(int a[],int key);
int main()
{
  int arr[20000],n,i,key,mid;


  FILE *fptr;

  //read sorted list file!
  if((fptr = fopen("sorted.txt","r"))==NULL){
    printf("Error in reading file !\n");
    return 0;
  }
  //array of sorted list!
  while(!feof(fptr)){
    if(!feof(fptr)){
      fscanf(fptr,"%d",&arr[i]);
      i++;}

  }

  printf("\nEnter element to be found:");
  scanf("%d",&key);
  mid=isearch(arr,key);
  printf("\nFound at position %d",mid+1);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
int isearch(int a[],int key)
{
  int low=0,high=19999,mid;
  while(a[low]<key&&a[high]>=key)
  {
    mid=low+(high-low)*(key-a[low])/(a[high]-a[low]);
    if(a[mid]<key)
      low=mid+1;
    else if(a[mid]>key)
      high=mid-1;
    else
      return mid;
  }
  if(a[low]==key)
    return low;
  else
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: What did you see when you added print statements? What happens when you step through in the debugger? Why is `high=19999` hard-coded?

Comment: I am really in hurry and could not define another variable. 
By entering a value I mean searching for a key.

Comment: File is not bigger than that. I am new to programming sorry for not good optimized code.

Comment: @chrisaycock See the headline ... this is an interpolation search, not a binary search. As for the question about what "enter" means, look at the source code ... it contains that word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm assumes that all of the values of `a` have been set, but you don't guarantee that ... what if your file has fewer than 20000 entries?

And suppose that `arr[19999]` is, say, 100000, and you search for 200000, `mid` will be set to a value greater than `high` and you get undefined behavior. You need to check that `mid` is within `low` .. `high`. And to avoid the first problem, you should pass low and high as parameters to your search function (or just the array size == `high + 1`, since `low` is always initially 0).

I suggest looking at any of the numerous examples of interpolation search algorithms available on-line and in books on algorithms.